# Embeddable commenting systems comparison?

Tags: web-services, service, comments

I need embeddable commenting system for web site where I can control posts. I want to delete posts I don't want to see and think that you can't do that if you use FB embeddable comments.

There is DISQUS, FB comments and many more solutions. What do you think is best? For me controlling comments, deletion of unwanted ones and banning users is priority n1.

Ideal solutions would be comment management that allows my users to login via numerous systems, like stackoverlow, and allow me to manage them, like stackoverflow does, but embeddable!

Opt out but possibility for posting to parent service is likeable feature

Looking for best solution! thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with DISQUS, or if 'social' features aren't that important I'd choose IntenseDebate.

DISQUS has all the features you mentioned above (minus posting comments to another service, but 'likes' can be propagated to Facebook and Twitter).

IntenseDebate has probably better spam detection (it's managed by the same guys which run WordPress.com) but it lacks some features - you can login only with IntenseDebate account, WP.com account or by typing in OpenID URL (most of Facebook users probably don't realize they have one without so it's more or less useless without a 'Login with Facebook button'), but it has better customization features than DISQUS (easily modifiable CSS) and some sort of plugins you can install (haven't seen lot of those).

Also, there's [Echo](http://aboutecho.com/comments-demo.html) - it has all the features you need, but it's not free - price ranges from $10 to $100 per month.

Comment: thx for the great post. i think this summarises all questions, but will keep thread open for few days

Comment: Note that Disqus can optionally integrate with Akismet if spam proves to be a persistant issue.